# PHP parse_str and special characters

Tags: php, parsing

I'm using parse_str to get a raw value from a URL (which is obviously entered by the user), and I'm wondering if there's anything I should to to make it safe before I use it (i.e. convert special characters like '<').

I noticed that the function does remove some characters, but I couldn't find the specifics anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the exact same thing as you would with GET data. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php. Also make sure to pass in the array parameter, or the user could override variables in the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlentities() and then parse_str() or parse_url() function